# Selenium Python Check if dropdown is selected with the expected value. I am getting False

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a method to check if the drop down field has the selected value.
The value selected in the drop down in the GUI is "PAF".
I am using first_selected_option from the Select class which should check the selected value from the drop down field.
I use an If Then Else to check if the value from the drop down matches the expected value of "PAF"
I am getting False instead of True.

Here is my Selenium Webdriver Python code snippet:

```
def is_dropdown_selected_from_advanced_cleaning_output_tab(self, field):
    selected_dropdown_option = Select(self.get_element(*MainPageLocators.mappings_paf_output_dropdown)).first_selected_option
    print (str(selected_dropdown_option))
    if (str(selected_dropdown_option)) == field:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

from my TestCase class the call to the method:

```
self.assertTrue(mappings.is_dropdown_selected_from_advanced_cleaning_output_tab("PAF"))
```

In the GUI PAF is selected in the drop down.  Why is it returning false?  What is wrong with my code?

I think I am not getting the string value correctly into the variable selected_dropdown_option
I tried (str(selected_dropdown_option))  Is this not the correct way to get the string value?

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0):

I haven`t tested this, but try this. It looks like you try to cast your webelement to a string, you should get the text. e.g : selected_dropdown_option.text

```
def is_dropdown_selected_from_advanced_cleaning_output_tab(self, field):      
    selected_dropdown_option = Select(self.get_element(*MainPageLocators.mappings_paf_output_dropdown))
    selected_dropdown_option.select_by_visible_text(field)
    selected_text = selected_dropdown_option.text
    if(selected_text == field):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I get the error: AttributeError: Select instance has no attribute 'text'

Comment: What does first_selected_option do?  Shouldn't that tell you what has been selected in the drop down field?

Comment: what if you do :
selected.text = selected_dropdown_option.first_selected_option.text

Yes, that should give you the selected element